# Check RAM, CPU usage and Disk space from a remote computer

Tags: powershell, cpu, wmi, firewall, ram

Using WMI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) I wrote a powershell to monitor Ram, CPU and CPU usage **of a remote computer** like the following:

```
$CompObject =  Get-WmiObject -Class WIN32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $remotePcName
$Memory = ((($CompObject.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $CompObject.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $CompObject.TotalVisibleMemorySize)
```

The computers are connected to the same network and can possibly be joined into the same Domain.
My question is: can a firewall somehow block the execution of my powershell and prevent me from being able to calculate the value of a resource on a remote computer?
If so, which firewall rule should I change?

Comment: Have you tried using the more modern version `Get-CimInstance`?

Comment: get-wmiobject uses dcom and get-ciminstance uses wsman (powershell remote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can a firewall somehow block the execution of my powershell and prevent me from being able to calculate the value of a resource on a remote computer?

### Yes!

> If so, which firewall rule should I change?

`Get-WmiObject` will default to WMI-over-RPC for remote transport, so you'll want to follow the guidance for [allowing WMI remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-starting-with-vista#windows-firewall-settings) on networked Windows computers.

As of writing, the rule group in question is named `Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)`:

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup 'Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)'
```